# Do US citizens need a visa for Turkey?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, turkey, american-airlines

I understand that Turkey does not belong to Schengen area. So would I need to have a visa to visit Turkey?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NOTE: Due to changing circumstances related to US citizens this answer is NOT currently correct.  Turkey is no longer issuing e-visas to US citizens, and visa-on-arrivals are only available to US citizens under very restricted circumstances (non-US residents, and some people related to Turkish citizens).**

**Exact circumstances are changing every few weeks, so I would suggest researching the exact situation before visiting Turkey as any answers on Travel.SE may be outdated quickly**

Yes you need a visa to enter Turkey, according to [Turkish Ministry Of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa)

> United States of America: Ordinary and official passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. They can obtain three month-multiple entry visas from Turkish diplomatic representations abroad and also via the website [www.evisa.gov.tr](http://www.evisa.gov.tr).

Please note, no more visa stickers on border crossings, you have to obtain the e-visa in advance:

> As of April 17, 2013, electronic visa (e-Visa) replaces “sticker visa” which was issued at the border crossings.  Applicants just need to log on to www.evisa.gov.tr , provide the requested information, (after the application is approved) make online payment and download their e-Visa.

The e-visa is easy to obtain and takes 24 hours to be issued, as mentioned in the [FAQ](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/) page:

> Your e-Visa will be e-mailed to you within 24 hours after completion of your 
>   application.

**Note:** The e-Visa's introduced in 2013 are now becoming mandatory. Sticker visas will not be available at border crossings beginning April 10th, 2014. If you needed a visa before, you *must* now obtain it in advance. This includes US citizens. There are even more restrictions on arrival for many other countries.

Comment: Can't Americans get a visa-on-arrival?

Comment: @hippietrail open the first link, it says no more.

Comment: When I was there in November you certainly could get a Visa-on-Arrival.  As per Caleb's update, it appears these may be going away in April - but until then either the e-Visa or the sticker-on-arrival are available.

Answer (score 5):

As of April 2016, it looks like on-arrival visas are still available, but only for certain countries (US citizens can still get one, along with 35 other countries).

From the Turkish e-Visa webpage: https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/i-do-not-want-to-apply-for-an-e-visa-can-i-get-a-visa-on-arrival/

> Q:  I do not want to apply for an e-Visa. Can I get a visa on arrival?
>
> A: Yes. If you are a citizen of one of the countries listed below and
>   you meet the required criteria, you can obtain a visa on arrival.
>   Kindly visit the Ministry's website (www.mfa.gov.tr) to learn more
>   about these requirements.
>
> - Antigua and Barbuda
> - Armenia
> - Australia
> - Austria
> - Bahamas
> - Bahrain
> - Barbados
> - Belgium
> - Canada
> - Croatia
> - Dominica
> - Dominican Republic
> - Estonia
> - Greek Cypriot Administration of Southern Cyprus
> - Grenada
> - Haiti
> - Hong Kong (BN(O))
> - Indonesia
> - Ireland
> - Jamaica
> - Latvia
> - Lithuania
> - Maldives
> - Malta
> - Mauritius
> - Mexico
> - Netherlands
> - Norway
> - Oman
> - Poland
> - Portugal
> - Saint Lucia
> - Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
> - Spain
> - U.S.A
> - United Kingdom

<strike>They're out of order on the website, so apologies for that :)</strike>

I would still suggest doing it online when possible, as it will greatly reduce the amount of headache you'll deal with on arrival. It is suggested to apply for your e-Visa more than 48hrs before arrival.

Comment: What do you mean by out of order ?

Comment: Non-alphabetical order of the countries. Though I'd actually forgotten to remove that line after cleaning up the list a bit. Disregard!

Answer (score 2):

I'm an American citizen and I entered Turkey about a year ago and just obtained the visa upon arrival (at the airport). The cost was about $20. I did not have to obtain the visa ahead of time. For a US citizen, the following website is useful to determine if a visa is needed ahead of time for all destinations.

http://travel.state.gov/travel/travel_1744.html

Comment: As of April 17, 2013, this is not applicable and you have to obtain an e-visa in advance.

Comment: The 2013 date is when they STARTED offering e-Visa's. They will be mandatory starting April 10th, 2014. This answer should be considered obsolete.

Comment: The state department site often has incorrect information. It's a good resource for initial research, but anyone actually traveling to another country should (if possible) confirm the requirements with that country's authorities before traveling. For example, for several Schengen countries it overstates the passport validity requirements, which has led to some confusion on this site.

Comment: It changed Turkey is now aplying e-visa. 
You passport must be valide at least 60 days.
You can make your visa request on internet and pay the visa by your credit card.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [**here**](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/data/KONSOLOSLUK/e-visa-fees-en-31-december.pdf), visas can still be obtained on arrival at **airports for certain nationalities** (the ones listed), either in sticker form or as e-visas through kiosks depending on the airport.

No visas on arrival at land crossings though - when I crossed from Georgia at Sarp now in April the visa desk was completely desolate.

The [E-visa Website](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/i-do-not-want-to-apply-for-an-e-visa-can-i-get-a-visa-on-arrival/) confirms the same.

So the other answers are only partially correct.